# Android get Activity with intentfilter launcher from package name programatically

Tags: android, android-activity, package, android-package-managers

I have this package name from a third party application:

```
"com.example.packagename"
```

This application has a activity with an intentFilter with a category Launcher:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

How can I retrieve programmatically this activity name from the package name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the laucher activity of the third party Termux app(package name : "com.termux").

**Snipplet : Approach 1**

If you want the **activity name** and component names,

```
String packageName =  "com.termux";
Intent i= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if(i != null && i.getComponent()!=null){
    Log.i("Activity", " Activity getComponent : " +i.getComponent().toString());
    Log.i("Activity", " Activity getClassName: " +i.getComponent().getClassName());
    Log.i("Activity", " Activity getShortClassName : " +i.getComponent().getShortClassName());
} else{
    Log.i("Activity", " Activity not found");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Activity getComponent : ComponentInfo{com.termux/com.termux.app.TermuxActivity}
Activity getClassName: com.termux.app.TermuxActivity
Activity getShortClassName : .app.TermuxActivity
```

**Snipplet: : Approach 2**:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setPackage("com.termux");
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
Collections.sort(activityList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

for (ResolveInfo temp : activityList) {
    Log.i("Activity", " Activity :  " +temp.activityInfo.name);

}
```

**Output:**

```
Activity:  Activity :  com.termux.app.TermuxActivity
```

**Note:**

If you want to **start the Launcher activity** of a package,

```
String packageName =  "com.termux";
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if(i != null){
    startActivity(i);
} else{
    Log.i("Activity", "package not found, ensure the "+packageName+" is installed.");
}
```

If you want to **find the package name from the Launcher activity** name,

```
String activityName = "TermuxActivity";

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
Collections.sort(activityList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
for (ResolveInfo temp : activityList) {
    if(temp.activityInfo.name.endsWith(activityName)){
        Log.i("ActivityCheck", " Activity : " +temp.activityInfo.name+ " package name: " +temp.activityInfo.packageName);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
ActivityCheck:  Activity : com.termux.app.TermuxActivity package name: com.termux
```

Comment: Very clear answer! And If I can just ask a linked question (the opposite one actually): Can I get the package name from an activity programatically?

Comment: You mean, if you give "TermuxActivity", the code returns  its package name "com.termux" ? In that case you can use the  approach #2. but the activity has to be the laucher activity.

Comment: Updated the  answer. please check and mark whether it is useful or not.